# inequality of logarithmic derivatives

Tags: calculus, inequality

What can we say about $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ when we know the following about their log-derivatives: $\frac{f'}{f} < \frac{g'}{g}$? I am fully aware the question is too vague but I was wondering whether such an inequality has been used somewhere (math, physics) to reach some interesting conclusions about the relationship between $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.

Comment: Consider the derivative of $f/g$ ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume here that $f,g\ge0$, since after all the logarithmic derivative is supposed to be the derivative of $\log f$. Define $$L(f)=f'/f.$$It's easy to  see that $$L(fg)=L(f)+F(g)$$and $L(f/g)=L(f)-L(g)$, from the product rule and quotient rule.

So $L(f)>L(g)$ says precisely that $L(f/g)>0$. This is equivalent to $(f/g)'>0$.